# How to save form data to XML or CSV?

Tags: c#, xml, csv, wpf-controls, save

We have currently built a application that uses both textbox and combo boxes.

We want to create a save button in a User Control Library that we have already built, and have it save all the data currently entered into an XML or CSV. The easier of the two would be preferred however I feel they're most likely the same difficulty.

I am using WPF! I would like to make it so that the data is stored to a file. Nothing amazing needs to happen to the file, it's just a case of saving the data from the different textboxes, and comboBoxes and then just having them stored within a document.

Comment: They're both easy. Is this for WinForms or a web app? Im guessing by "forms" you are referring to html forms and that this is then a web app, right?

Comment: We're using WPF sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's something to try. First, because you're using WPF, you need a way to get the controls of a specific type. Here is an extension method for you:

```
public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildren<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        List<T> childControls = new List<T>();
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject childControl = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (childControl is T)
            {
                childControls.Add((T)childControl);
            }
        }
        return childControls;
    }
}
```

Next, you need a method to create your CSV:

```
public string ToCsv(params IEnumerable<Control>[] controls)
{
    return ToCsv(true, controls);
}

public string ToCsv(bool outputColumnNames, params IEnumerable<Control>[] controls)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (outputColumnNames)
    {
        foreach (var textBox in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            sb.Append(textBox.Name);
            sb.Append(",");
        }

        foreach (var comboBox in controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
        {
            sb.Append(comboBox.Name);
            sb.Append(",");
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    }

    sb.AppendLine();

    foreach (var textBox in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        sb.Append(textBox.Text);
        sb.Append(",");
    }

    foreach (var comboBox in controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
    {
        sb.Append(comboBox.Text);
        sb.Append(",");
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and lastly... use it like this:

```
var textBoxes = grid.GetChildren<TextBox>();
var comboBoxes = grid.GetChildren<ComboBox>();
string csv = ToCsv(textBoxes, comboBoxes);
```

In the above, `grid` is defined on my test form like this:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
```

and the controls are children of that. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lines = new List<string>();
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
            lines.Add(string.Format("{0},{1}", ((TextBox)c).Name, ((TextBox)c).Text));
        if (c is ComboBox)
            lines.Add(string.Format("{0},{1}", ((ComboBox)c).Name, ((ComboBox)c).Text));
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"data.csv", lines);
}
```

For WPF:

A helper:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var lines = new List<string>();
    foreach (TextBox tb in WindowHelper.FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(this))
        lines.Add(string.Format("{0},{1}", tb.Name, tb.Text));
    foreach (ComboBox cb in WindowHelper.FindVisualChildren<ComboBox>(this))
        lines.Add(string.Format("{0},{1}", cb.Name, cb.Text));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"data.csv", lines);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to cast to `TextBox` or `ComboBox`.. both inherit from `Control` and the `Text` and `Name` properties are on that class.

Comment: Hey Joey! We can't seem to get "Controls" to work. It says no extension method can be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference) we are already using the "Using.System.Windows.Controls" name space. Any suggestions

Comment: Joey's is for WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: Ah okay, is there a similar way in which we could make this in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty broad question, but the general outline is that you would have to serialize the data into whichever format you end up going with (which would depend on what you plan to do with the data later: Are you sending it to another customer who needs it in one format or the other? Are you just saving the data to have it on record?) Also, bear in mind that CSV is a flat file, i.e. each line of the file is a row and each comma-separated value is in a column, whereas XML is a hierarchical format, i.e. a tree, like HTML. This makes CSV better for storing things like database rows and makes XML better for storing hierarchical things, like an object graph, a document layout, etc. So it really depends on what you're trying to do (and you might want to add more detail to your question in order to get better answers).

Comment: Thanks Dan! Will try to word the questions better from now. Still a C# novice :)